# Ubuntu 17.04: External USB mouse is not working

Tags: usb, mouse, 17.04

My touchpad mouse is working fine, but my external USB mouse don't, he's dead...in my computer, in others works fine.

I already tried the solutions from:
[USB mouse is not working for Ubuntu 14.04 after updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743708/usb-mouse-is-not-working-for-ubuntu-14-04-after-updating)

and:
[USB Mouse not working after installing Ubuntu 16.04 - Persistent Fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763511/usb-mouse-not-working-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-persistent-fix)

But still is not working.

The lsbusb recognizes it as you can see:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:e006 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:9209 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 045e:0737 Microsoft Corp. Compact Optical Mouse 500
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Can anybody help me please?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Is it listed in `xinput`?

Comment: No, with Mouse this is the result from xinput:

orlando_olguin|ooo-laptop|~ $ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL06F2:00 06CB:75DA Touchpad            id=10 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad               id=12 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=6 [slave  keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn off mouse acceleration by adding a file to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, like in this thread: [How to disable mouse acceleration in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/887871/702759) ?

This file could be called `90-mouse-accel-disable.conf`, `50-mouse-acceleration.conf` or something like that.

If yes, then you have to change value `-1` in line `Option "AccelerationProfile" "-1"` to `0`. Apparently there were [some changes](https://askubuntu.com/a/906640/702759) in the underlying code in 17.04.

Mine `50-mouse-acceleration.conf` looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "My Mouse"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
    Option "AccelerationProfile" "0"
    Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
    Option "AccelProfile" "flat"
EndSection
```

Comment: Hi, nope, I didn't disable the acceleration, in fact, I like it.